# Workflow engine for Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, workflow

For our new SOA, we are looking at Kafka as a message broker.

I wish to ask, what are our options to organize workflows in messaging?

It looks like there should be a coordinator/supervisor service which concentrates knowledge about an order, in which messages should be published and processed. And probably writing it from scratch is not a good idea.

I seen a few workflow engines, but not one which is designed specifically for use with Kafka, or advised to be used with it. I'm afraid that looking at Kafka, we've chosen the wrong tool, because building complex and reliable workflows is a must from our perspectives.

Any advice please: workflow engine? Another messaging platform? Go to work in McDonalds?:)

Comment: This might be worth a read: https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/comparing-confluent-platform-with-traditional-messaging-middleware/. Kafka's a lot more than 'just' a message broker, and how people architect with it tends to differ from just a stock MB.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt thanks for sharing. We aware of these features of Kafka, but it does not look like they diminish the need to control/audit the workflows?

Comment: Have you considered any other technologies like RabbitMQ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous we are open for alternatives in general, but since a while use Kafka and it seem to fit our needs. Maybe I'm wrong, making an assumption that workflow relates to MB at all, but I have feeling that workflow engine can subscribe directly to Kafka topics and get notified of events without being notified from services code...

Comment: @IvanZverev If you just need a message broker, then Kafka would be an overkill here. As Robin has already pointed out, Kafka is a lot more than a message queue/broker. It depends on your use-case(s) and requirements though.